# JSON data being received in an incomplete format in php?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, json

I'm building a super simple website application that calls an API to retrieve backlink data for any website inputted into said application by the user. The data the API sends includes strings (e.g. http://www.domain.com/?feed=rss) and numbers and is in JSON format. I parse the response as follows:

```
mozResponse = JSON.parse(response);
```

I then iterate through this data, pushing only the data I want into 2 new arrays (arry, arry1), declared as follows:

```
arry = []; 
arry1 = [];
```

Pushing as follows:

```
arry.push({id:i, url:mozResponse[i].uu, pa:Math.round(mozResponse[i].upa), da:Math.round(mozResponse[i].pda), anchor:mozResponse[i].lt});
```

I then Stringify these two arrays as follows:

```
    var cautionArrayString = JSON.stringify(arry);
    var dangerArrayString = JSON.stringify(arry1);
```

I'm using a JavaScript XMLHTTPRequest to POST this data to a php file as follows:

```
var queryString = "email=" + Email + "&caution=" + cautionArrayString + "&danger=" + dangerArrayString;
xhr1.onreadystatechange=Response1;
xhr1.open("post","http://example.com/emails.php",true);
xhr1.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr1.send(queryString);
```

The php file then reads:

```
$caution = $_POST['caution']; 
$danger = $_POST['danger'];
```

I'm aware at this point I should decode the JSON again upon originally doing so I ended up with a broken array. Here's what the console.log reads AFTER posting the data to the php file, with the php file using:

```
echo($_POST['caution']);
echo ($_POST['danger']);
```

Console.log shows:

```
[{"id":3,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor”:”Example”},    
{"id":4,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor":"thank you gifts"},  
{"id":5,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor":"flowers"},
{"id":6,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor":"thank you"},
{"id":7,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor":"Arrive in Style"},
{"id":8,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor":"dignity"},
{"id":9,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor":"Beautiful in Blue"},
{"id":10,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor":"Blooming Garden Basket"},
{"id":11,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor":"Country Basket Blooms"},
{"id":12,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor":"Heart’s Delight"},
{"id":13,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor":"Make a Wish"},
{"id":14,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor":"Moondance"},
{"id":15,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor":"Queen’s Court"},
{"id":16,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor":"Sweet as Sugar"},
{"id":17,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor":"flower colors"},
{"id":18,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor":"Always Yours"},
{"id":19,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor":"Sunrise, Sunset"},
{"id":20,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor":"Uniquely Chic"},
{"id":21,"url":"example.com/best/index.php?page=1998","pa":25,"da":31,"anchor":"example.ca/"},
{"id":22,"url":"example.com/best/index.php?page=1994","pa":25,"da":31,"anchor":"example.ca/"},
{"id":23,"url":"example.ca/","pa":25,"da":16,"anchor”:”example”},
{"id":28,"url":"example.ca/article/156-best-cms-for-small-business","pa":22,"da":39,"anchor":"example.ca/"},
{"id":30,"url":"example.ca/blog.html","pa":21,"da":15,"anchor":"example.ca/"},
{"id":31,"url":"example.ca/beyond-the-flowers-choosing-a-vase/","pa":20,"da":12,"anchor”:”Example”},
{"id":32,"url":"example.ca/beyond-the-flowers-choosing-a-vase/","pa":20,"da":12,"anchor":"Arrive in Style"},
{"id":33,"url":"example.ca/beyond-the-flowers-choosing-a-vase/","pa":20,"da":12,"anchor":"Beautiful in Blue"},
{"id":34,"url":"example.ca/beyond-the-flowers-choosing-a-vase/","pa":20,"da":12,"anchor":"Blooming Garden Basket"},
{"id":35,"url":"example.ca/beyond-the-flowers-choosing-a-vase/","pa":20,"da":12,"anchor":"Country Basket Blooms"},
{"id":36,"url":"example.ca/beyond-the-flowers-choosing-a-vase/","pa":20,"da":12,"anchor":"Heart’s Delight"},
{"id":37,"url":"example.ca/beyond-the-flowers-choosing-a-vase/","pa":20,"da":12,"anchor":"Make a Wish"},
{"id":38,"url":"example.ca/gifts.html","pa":19,"da":11,"anchor”:”example- <span class=\"catlist\"> Flowers</span>"},
{"id":39,"url":"example.ca/category/flowers/","pa":19,"da":16,"anchor”:”Example”},
{"id":40,"url":"example.ca/category/floral-fauna/","pa":19,"da":16,"anchor”:”Example”},
{"id":41,"url":"nunavut.findstuffhere.ca/nunavut/?feed=rss2[]
```

Where you can see AT THE END that the 1st array is incomplete and the 2nd is empty (as it should be!). So my question here is, what's causing this and how can I fix it?

**Things to Note**

- I use 3 URL's as inputs to test. The data is complete with 1 URL, but 2 others (the example above included) return this incomplete JSON, seemingly because of a query string being a part of a URL returned from the API?
- I `console.log(mozResponse)` and the output is as expected
- I `console.log(arry) and console.log(arry1)` AFTER iterating through mozResponse and pushing data from mozResponse to arry/arry1 and the output is a complete array
- I `console.log(arry)` and `console.log(arry1)` AFTER applying JSON.stringify but BEFORE posting to php and the output is complete

**Things I've explored**

- I originally thought this was the result of one of the URL's that the
  API returns including a query string (e.g. ?feed=rss2 where it
  breaks) however prior to this break point there are query strings
  being handled fine
- Doesn't seem to be a JSON error as I used
  json_last_error(); and it returned 0.
- Also doesn't seem to be a a
  JSON/POST char limit thing because it returns broken JSON when I
  input a different URL (the output from the $_POST for this URL also
  breaks following a query string, not sure if this is coincidence)
- Suhosin isn't present
- Created a phpinfo page to check max_vars but the limit is large

Any help is greatly appreciated!

*different quotes are from copy/pasting!

Comment: I didn't really read the question but I noticed that on the first line there are different type of quotes:
`[{"id":3,"url":"example.ca/","pa":26,"da":12,"anchor”:”Example”},    `

Comment: They are from copy pasting as @jeroen said! Thanks for pointing this out though, I'll amend my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to encode your values for use in a query string:

```
var cautionArrayString = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(arry));
var dangerArrayString = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(arry1));

var queryString = "email=" + encodeURIComponent(Email) + "&caution=" + cautionArrayString + "&danger=" + dangerArrayString;
```

Converting it to json does not automatically encode it correctly for use in a url so characters in your values could break the query string.

Assuming the different quotes are caused by copy-pasting...

Comment: Holy crap, thank you for your clear answer. It's all fixed now! Thank you!